# Using Jquery to return many values to be updated within html

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, post

I could not think of a good title to describe what im trying to figure out, but i have this code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $.get('/battleship/update_game/{{info.gameid}}/{{user.username}}', function(data){
           //All Html elements to be updated
        });
    },3000);
    });
```

the idea is that it sends a request for information, and then gets back multiple values ie an array of imformation. i cannot figure out how to do it. I am also using django, so my method of returning 'data' back is

```
return HttpResponse(myinformation)
```

what i want is to say

```
return HttpResponse([info1,info2,info3,info4])
```

and then be able to access those values from the javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I need to do some operations and I don't want to reload the page I use a JQuery call to Ajax, I make the pertinent operations in AJAX and then receive the AJAX response in the JQuery function without leaving or reloading the page. I'll make an easy example here for you to understand the basics of this:

JQuery function, placed in the template you need

```
function form_post(){       
    //You have to get the data from any tag in the template
    var var1 = $('#yourelement').val()
    //or get them using django variables
    var var2 = "{{django_variable}}"
    var data = []  // Create a list if you need to send multiple values
    data.push(var1)
    data.push(var2)
    $.ajax({  //Call ajax function sending the data you need
      url: "/ajax_url/",  //This is the url of the ajax view where you make the search 
      type: 'POST',
      data: "data="+data
        success: function(response) {
            result = JSON.parse(response);  // Get the results sended from ajax to here
            if (result.error) { // If the function fails
                // Error
                alert(result.error_text);
            } else {  // Success

                    //Here do whatever you need with the result;                                                  
                } 
            }
        }
    });              
    }
```

You have to realize that I cannot finish the code without knowing what kind of results you're getting or how do you want to display them, so you need to retouch this code on your needs.

AJAX function called by JQuery

Remember you need to add an url for this Ajax function in your urls.py something like:

`url(r'^/ajax_url/?$', 'your_project.ajax.ajax_view', name='ajax_view'),`

`your_project.ajax.ajax_view` this meant you need a file called `ajax.py` in same folder as views.py

Then your AJAX function, it's like a normal Django View, but add this function into ajax.py

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf 
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt 
from django.utils import simplejson

@csrf_exempt
def ajax_view(request):    
    response = []
    #Here you have to enter code here 
    #to receive the data you send here by POST       
    data = request.POST['data']
    #Do the operations you need with the form information
    #Add the data you need to send back to a list/dictionary like response
    response = whatever you need
    #And return it to the JQuery function `enter code here`(simplejson.dumps is to convert to JSON)
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response))
```

So, without leaving the page you receive via javascript a list of items that you sended from ajax view.

So you can update the any tag you need using JQuery

I know that this can be so confusing at the beginning but once you are used to AJAX this kind of operations without leaving or reloading the page are easy to do.

The basics for understanding is something like:

1. JQuery function called on click or any event you need
2. JQuery get some values on the template and send them to AJAX via
   POST
3. Receive that information in AJAX via POST
4. Do whatever you need in AJAX like a normal DJango view
5. Convert your result to JSON and send back to the JQuery function
6. JQuery function receive the results from AJAX and you can do
   whatever you need

**Tip** When you send variables to AJAX you need to know that the values you send are going to be converted to string. You'll received strings in the AJAX view via POST. When you create the response in the AJAX view to send it back to JQuery in the template, you need to convert the data to json too as you can see in the response of the ajax function `return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response))` `simplejson.dumps()` convert the data to json